# How to get the List(contain huge data) in javascript from session?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I have a List in jsp scriptlet and I stored that list into session. That list contain very huge data.

like the following.....

```
110:ListTypeVasParam:51:null:null:9910101002-Test@ :110::ListTypeVasParam::51::null::null::9911000002-Test@:110:TextTypeVasParam:50:text:null:null-null@ :110::TextTypeVasParam::50::text::null::null-null@:111:ListTypeVasParam:54:null:null:99101000002-Test@ :111::ListTypeVasParam::54::null::null::9910101000002-Test@:111:ListTypeVasParam:55:null:null:1-YU@2-Safaricom Kenya@3-Airtel@ :111::ListTypeVasParam::55::null::null::1-YU@2-Safaricom Kenya@3-Airtel@:111:TextTypeVasParam:52:text:null:null-null@ :111::TextTypeVasParam::52::text::null::null-null@:111:TextTypeVasParam:53:text:null:null-null@ :111::TextTypeVasParam::53::text::null::null-null@:112:ListTypeVasParam:58:null:null:9910101000002-Test@ :112::ListTypeVasParam::58::null::null::9910101000002-Test@:112:ListTypeVasParam:56:null:null:test1-test1@ :112::ListTypeVasParam::56::null::null::test1-test1@:112:TextTypeVasParam:57:text:null:null-null@ :112::TextTypeVasParam::57::text::null::null-null@:113:TextTypeVasParam:60:text:null:null-null@ :113::TextTypeVasParam::60::text::null::null-null@:113:TextTypeVasParam:61:text:null:null-null@ :113::TextTypeVasParam::61::text::null::null-null@:113:ListTypeVasParam:59:null:null:1-YU@2-Safaricom Kenya@3-Airtel@ :113::ListTypeVasParam::59::null::null::1-YU@2-Safaricom Kenya@3-Airtel@:373:ListTypeVasParam:44:null:null:9910101000002-Test@ :373::ListTypeVasParam::44::null::null::9910101000002-Test@:373:TextTypeVasParam:42:text:null:null-null@ :373::TextTypeVasParam::42::text::null::null-null@:373:TextTypeVasParam:43:text:null:null-null@ :373::TextTypeVasParam::43::text::null::null-null@:374:ListTypeVasParam:49:null:null:9910101000002-Test@ :374::ListTypeVasParam::49::null::null::9910101000002-Test@:374:TextTypeVasParam:48:text:null:null-null@ :374::TextTypeVasParam::48::text::null::null-null@:374:TextTypeVasParam:45:text:null:null-null@ :374::TextTypeVasParam::45::text::null::null-null@:374:TextTypeVasParam:47:text:null:null-null@ :374::TextTypeVasParam::47::text::null::null-null@:374:TextTypeVasParam:46:text:null:null-null@ :374::TextTypeVasParam::46::text::null::null-null@:120:ListTypeVasParam:64:null:null:9910101000002-Test@ :120::ListTypeVasParam::64::null::null::9910101000002-Test@:120:ListTypeVasParam:63:null:null:BESCOM-BESCOM@ :120::ListTypeVasParam::63::null::null::BESCOM-BESCOM@:120:TextTypeVasParam:65:text:null:null-null@ :120::TextTypeVasParam::65::text::null::null-null@:121:ListTypeVasParam:68:null:null:9910101000002-Test@ :121::ListTypeVasParam::68::null::null::9910101000002-Test@:121:TextTypeVasParam:69:text:null:null-null@ :121::TextTypeVasParam::69::text::null::null-null@:121:TextTypeVasParam:67:text:null:null-null@ :121::TextTypeVasParam::67::text::null::null-null@:121:TextTypeVasParam:66:text:null:null-null@ :121::TextTypeVasParam::66::text::null::null-null@:122:TextTypeVasParam:70:text:null:null-null@ :122::TextTypeVasParam::70::text::null::null-null@:122:TextTypeVasParam:72:text:null:null-null@ :122::TextTypeVasParam::72::text::null::null-null@:122:TextTypeVasParam:71:text:null:null-null@ :122::TextTypeVasParam::71::text::null::null-null@:131:ListTypeVasParam:592:null:null:99101000002-Test@ :131::ListTypeVasParam::592::null::null::9910101000002-Test@:131:ListTypeVasParam:4:null:null:USD-USD@GBP-GBP@INR-INR@ :131::ListTypeVasParam::4::null::null::USD-USD@GBP-GBP@INR-INR@:133:TextTypeVasParam:92:text:null:null-null@ :133::TextTypeVasParam::92::text::null::null-null@:134:TextTypeVasParam:91:text:null:null-null@ :134::TextTypeVasParam::91::text::null::null-null@:67:TextTypeVasParam:2:password:null:null-null@ :67::TextTypeVasParam::2::password::null::null-null@:67:TextTypeVasParam:3:password:null:null-null@ :67::TextTypeVasParam::3::password::null::null-null@:67:TextTypeVasParam:1:password:null:null-null@ :67::TextTypeVasParam::1::password::null::null-null@:138:TextTypeVasParam:5:text:null:null-null@ :138::TextTypeVasParam::5::text::null::null-null@:138:TextTypeVasParam:6:text:null:null-null@ :138::TextTypeVasParam::6::text::null::null-null@:103:ListTypeVasParam:15:null:null:9910101000002-Test@ :103::ListTypeVasParam::15::null::null::9910101000002-Test@:103:ListTypeVasParam:14:null:null:25-25@50-50@75-75@100-100@ :103::ListTypeVasParam::14::null::null::25-25@50-50@75-75@100-100@:104:ListTypeVasParam:17:null:null:9910101000002-Test@ :104::ListTypeVasParam::17::null::null::9910101000002-Test@:104:TextTypeVasParam:18:text:null:null-null@ :104::TextTypeVasParam::18::text::null::null-null@:104:TextTypeVasParam:19:text:null:null-null@ :104::TextTypeVasParam::19::text::null::null-null@:2:ListTypeVasParam:9:null:null:9910101000002-Test@ :2::ListTypeVasParam::9::null::null::9910101000002-Test@:2:ListTypeVasParam:8:null:null:Phone-Phone@SMS-SMS@ :2::ListTypeVasParam::8::null::null::Phone-Phone@SMS-SMS@:3:ListTypeVasParam:10:null:null:9910101000002-Test@ :3::ListTypeVasParam::10::null::null::9910101000002-Test@:3:ListTypeVasParam:11:null:null:Email-Email@Branch-Branch@Postal Address-Postal Address@ :3::ListTypeVasParam::11::null::null::Email-Email@Branch-Branch@Postal Address-Postal Address@:3:TextTypeVasParam:12:text:null:null-null@ :3::TextTypeVasParam::12::text::null::null-null@:3:TextTypeVasParam:13:text:null:null-null@ :3::TextTypeVasParam::13::text::null::null-null@:105:ListTypeVasParam:87:null:null:9910101000002-Test@ :105::ListTypeVasParam::87::null::null::9910101000002-Test@:105:ListTypeVasParam:86:null:null:LARGE.CREDIT-LARGE CREDIT@LARGE.DEBIT-LARGE DEBIT@MINIMUM.BALANCE-MINIMUM BALANCE@ :105::ListTypeVasParam::86::null::null::LARGE.CREDIT-LARGE CREDIT@LARGE.DEBIT-LARGE DEBIT@MINIMUM.BALANCE-MINIMUM BALANCE@:105:TextTypeVasParam:88:text:null:null-null@ :105::TextTypeVasParam::88::text::null::null-null@:106:ListTypeVasParam:90:null:null:9910101000002-Test@ :106::ListTypeVasParam::90::null::null::9910101000002-Test@:106:ListTypeVasParam:89:null:null:LARGE.CREDIT-LARGE CREDIT@LARGE.DEBIT-LARGE DEBIT@MINIMUM.BALANCE-MINIMUM BALANCE@ :106::ListTypeVasParam::89::null::null::LARGE.CREDIT-LARGE CREDIT@LARGE.DEBIT-LARGE DEBIT@MINIMUM.BALANCE-MINIMUM BALANCE@:107:ListTypeVasParam:21:null:null:9910101000002-Test@ :107::ListTypeVasParam::21::null::null::9910101000002-Test@:107:TextTypeVasParam:22:text:null:null-null@ :107::TextTypeVasParam::22::text::null::null-null@:107:ListTypeVasParam:20:null:null:1-Cheque(s) Lost@2-Cheque(s) Destroyed@3-Cheques Stolen@4-Bankers CHQ Lost\\Stolen@ :107::ListTypeVasParam::20::null::null::1-Cheque(s) Lost@2-Cheque(s) Destroyed@3-Cheques Stolen@4-Bankers CHQ Lost\\Stolen@:108:TextTypeVasParam:16:text:null:null-null@ :108::TextTypeVasParam::16::text::null::null-null@:116:ListTypeVasParam:74:null:null:9910101000002-Test@ :116::ListTypeVasParam::74::null::null::9910101000002-Test@:116:TextTypeVasParam:75:text:null:null-null@ :116::TextTypeVasParam::75::text::null::null-null@:116:TextTypeVasParam:76:text:null:null-null@ :116::TextTypeVasParam::76::text::null::null-null@:6:ListTypeVasParam:29:null:null:9910101000002-Test@ :6::ListTypeVasParam::29::null::null::9910101000002-Test@:6:ListTypeVasParam:26:null:null:Account Number-Account Number@Mobile Number-Mobile Number@ :6::ListTypeVasParam::26::null::null::Account Number-Account Number@Mobile Number-Mobile Number@:6:TextTypeVasParam:27:text:null:null-null@ :6::TextTypeVasParam::27::text::null::null-null@:6:TextTypeVasParam:28:text:null:null-null@ :6::TextTypeVasParam::28::text::null::null-null@:7:ListTypeVasParam:30:null:null:9910101000002-Test@ :7::ListTypeVasParam::30::null::null::9910101000002-Test@:7:TextTypeVasParam:33:text:null:null-null@ :7::TextTypeVasParam::33::text::null::null-null@:7:TextTypeVasParam:31:text:null:null-null@ :7::TextTypeVasParam::31::text::null::null-null@:7:TextTypeVasParam:34:text:null:null-null@ :7::TextTypeVasParam::34::text::null::null-null@:7:TextTypeVasParam:32:text:null:null-null@ :7::TextTypeVasParam::32::text::null::null-null@:7:TextTypeVasParam:591:text:null:null-null@ :7::TextTypeVasParam::591::text::null::null-null@:8:TextTypeVasParam:38:text:null:null-null@ :8::TextTypeVasParam::38::text::null::null-null@:8:ListTypeVasParam:40:null:null:Account Number-Account Number@Mobile Number-Mobile Number@ :8::ListTypeVasParam::40::null::null::Account Number-Account Number@Mobile Number-Mobile Number@:8:TextTypeVasParam:39:text:null:null-null@ :8::TextTypeVasParam::39::text::null::null-null@:9:ListTypeVasParam:41:null:null:testing1-testing1@testing-testing@ :9::ListTypeVasParam::41::null::null::testing1-testing1@testing-testing@:10:ListTypeVasParam:37:null:null:9910101000002-Test@ :10::ListTypeVasParam::37::null::null::9910101000002-Test@:10:ListTypeVasParam:36:null:null:testing1-testing1@testing-testing@ :10::ListTypeVasParam::36::null::null::testing1-testing1@testing-testing@:10:TextTypeVasParam:35:text:null:null-null@ :10::TextTypeVasParam::35::text::null::null-null@
```

When I accessing that list in javascript it doesn't allow that list. If I remove some data in the list then javascript allowed the list. I split the single list into multiple lists then also javascript doesn't allow the list.

**Please help me how to get the list in javascript that contain huge data in string format ?**

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single session's (sessions are small files saved on hard disk) highest capacity is `4kb`. You just can't store more than `4kb` of data in a session. So in your case, your data is not inside the session because of it's size and that's why you can't access it.

Alternatively you can store the data on the server side (may be using any database) and generate and assign a unique identifier/key for each peace of data and save the key in the session.

Answer (score 0):

Its not a good idea to store this much data in the session. You can use JSON to transfer this data to JavaScript. That is the best approach I think